# Personalized Accordion (like a list of Master-Details)

Tags: asp.net, accordion

I need to create an Accordion Ajax control that in the first Pane has a list of records
(for example Users).
When the web users clic on one of them, the other Panes have to be populated with details of this user.
For example, if I clic in the first record, Pane2 will be populated with LifeDetails, Pane3 with HomeDetails, Pane4 with JobDetails and so on.

Anyone has idea of how realize this?

Thanks a lot.

Luigi

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve this using http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion and http://pjax.heroku.com/ ...

Something along the lines of

```
 <div id="accordion">
      <h3><a href="#">pane1</a></h3>
      <div>
          <ul id="persons">
              <li><a href="person1.aspx">Person 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="person2.aspx">Person 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="person3.aspx">Person 3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Life Details</a></h3>
      <div>
          Some content here
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Home Details</a></h3>
      <div>
          Some content here
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Job Details </a></h3>
      <div>
          Some content here
      </div>
 </div>
```

For the markup. Then your JavaScript should be something like

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
            $('.persons').pjax('#accordion');
    });
</script>
```

And in your aspx you check for the `HTTP_X_PJAX` header (see [`xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', 'true')`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/heroku/jquery.pjax.js#L295)), and if it's present, you render just the `<div id="accordion">` for the selected item (without the Masterpage, just the `div`), if it's not present you render the whole page (with Masterpage).

Comment: Thank you Ramses, I'll try in this way.
Luigi